# Synonym for "geek" (computer geek) with positive connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

Something like "IT expert" or "computer expert" seems verbose. Is there something better? I *am* looking, though, for a word with that (IT/computer expert) meaning. Something like "mechanic", "actor", "designer"... But something general like "geek" is, as opposed to a more narrow meaning word like "developer".

(Before I'm asked why I think it has negative connotations: See [Wikipedia on Geek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geek): "with a general pejorative meaning")

Comment: Do you mean "geek" in general or a specific kind of geek (e.g. an "IT geek" or "computer geek")?

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin The latter.

Comment: Computer specialist/guru/expert etc.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul That's like the examples I mentioned in my question. I want something more succinct. Like "mechanic" (but for computer experts).

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul  I like "guru": it has stood the test of time and is positive.

Comment: Nerd? a single-minded expert in a particular technical field. "a computer nerd" (source Google)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [*computer guru*](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/computer%20guru), but if you need a single word, I'd suggest *techie*.

> **Techie (noun):** Someone who knows a lot about computers or other electronic equipment.
>
> [[Cambridge English Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/techie)

Lexico also gives *[computernik](https://www.lexico.com/definition/computernik)* and *[computer jock](https://www.lexico.com/definition/computer_jock)* for a computer expert/enthusiast.

Comment: In my experience 'guru' tends to be applied to software and network staff rather than hardware personnel whereas 'geek' is often applied more generally.

Comment: Techie is certainly the only single word I can think of that comes close to meaning a computer expert (although as the dictionary says, it could refer to an expert in related fields e.g. electronics). Lots of words for experts, a few words for people involved with computers, but nothing else that means computer expert.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *computer [aficionado](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aficionado)*? This lacks the negative connotation, but it may suggest more of a hobbyist than a professional.

Comment: Yes, as your reference says an aficionado is a person with interest and knowledge, but not necessarily a person who does the thing: you can be an aficionado from your armchair or as a spectator. Likewise, you can have a theoretical or armchair knowledge of computers without ever using one (some Computer Science professors seem to come into this category), but I suspect the OP is wanting someone with practical skills and experience not just knowledge.